# Python get for loop result into an array variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
code = []
def getCode():
    for data in range(59):
        code = []
        min = 9900
        max = 9999

        code1 = randint(min, max)
        code2 = randint(min, max)

        code = str(code1) + '/' + str(code2)
        # print(code)

        return code

print(getCode()) 

dat2 = pd.DataFrame({'code': [getCode()]})
```

Hi, I'm trying to get a list of the number from the for loop. example result should be `[[9900/9910],[9910/9920],.....]`. However the code above only return me `9900/9910` even if I declare the array variable.

Comment: Why is the `return` inside the for loop?

Comment: you have defined `code` variable thrice in your code

Comment: Also, you redeclare the empty list on each loop... Move the `code = []` outside the loop

Comment: Use `append`, not assignment `=`. You are changing `code` to `str`.

Comment: `code` is reset every time your loop iterates

Comment: Also, it seems like you want a list of singleton lists, so change to `[str(code1) + '/' + str(code2)]`

Comment: The entire thing could be replaced with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append to `code` each time through the loop, not assign to it. You shouldn't reinitialize it in the loop, and the `return` statement should be after the loop.

And if you want a 2-dimensional list, you need to wrap the concatenations in another list.

However, the loop can be replaced completely with a list comprehension.

```
def getCode():
    min = 9900
    max = 9999
    return [[str(randint(min, max)) + '/' + str(randint(min, max))] for _ in range(59)]
```